Disable Azure CI being triggered on template repository
While working on a test branch "release/v1.3" in our pipeline-templates repository, I noticed that CI was triggered on every pipeline using the templates.  Even though the applications are using a different version of the templates.
How can I stop this from happening again?
I've found a possible solution here: Azure DevOps : how to disable CI trigger on a YAML template pipeline?
But won't this disable all triggers?
So far, I've:

Enabled the "Disable implied YAML CI trigger" option.
Added "[skip ci]" to my commit messages.
Included "trigger: none" in my pipeline-template repository.
Verified that there are no tags on the pipeline-templates repository.
Created a dummy branch test/test-deploy, which also triggered CI.

Application repository (BitBucket - .pipelines/deployment_pipeline.yaml):
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
      - v*
pr: none

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: pipeline-templates
      type: git
      name: myproject/pipeline-templates
      ref: release/v1
extends:
  template: pipelines/deploy-service.yaml@pipeline-templates

Pipeline Template (Azure Devops Repository)
trigger: none

stages: ...
....


Have you checked with the suggestions shared in my answer below? Does it work for you? @John

You cannot use the template YAML to control the triggers of the pipeline YAML which is using the template YAML. Event if it is an extends template.
To disable/enable the CI trigger or other triggers for a pipeline, you need to directly configure the triggers in the pipeline YAML instead of the template YAML. See "CI triggers".

See below examples for a good understanding.

Example #1

The pipeline YAML.
# azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: pipeline-templates
    type: git
    name: templatesYAML
    ref: release/v1

extends:
  template: pipelines/template.yml@pipeline-templates


The template YAML on branch 'release/v1' from the repository resource (templatesYAML).
# pipelines/template.yml

trigger: none

stages:
. . .



Because the CI trigger is enabled with branches filter in the pipeline YAML (azure-pipelines.yml), the pipeline will be triggered when any update committed to the main branch of current repository (not the repository resource).

Example #2

The pipeline YAML.
# azure-pipelines.yml
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: pipeline-templates
    type: git
    name: templatesYAML
    ref: release/v1

extends:
  template: pipelines/template.yml@pipeline-templates


The template YAML on branch 'release/v1' from the repository resource (templatesYAML).
# pipelines/template.yml

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main

stages:
. . .



Because the CI trigger is disabled (trigger: none) in the pipeline YAML (azure-pipelines.yml), the pipeline will not be triggered when committing updates to the current repository.

EDIT:
As stated in the documentation "CI triggers", when the "Disable implied YAML CI trigger" setting is disabled, if you didn't specify any triggers, the default is implicitly enabling CI trigger on all  branches.



Thank you for your response, I'll try this out.
Do you have any clue how/why CI was previously triggered even though my pipeline-templates project didn't have any tags defined and pipeline yaml referenced another branch?

@John, In the pipeline YAML, if you do not explicitly use the 'trigger' key to configure the CI trigger, by default the pipeline will be triggered by CI when any changes committed to the repository. See EDIT in my answer above.
